# How to add .ui file in Visual Studio (2010) project and compile it

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, qt-designer

I'm new in using Qt and I have a problem. I have created a simple window (.ui File) with Qt Designer and saved it.

Now I want compile it with Visual Studio 2010 . How can I add an external .ui file into my Visual Studio Project and compile it?

Should I create a new class in the project? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The best option (and probably the only one unless you are using CMake or similar) is to use the official Visual Studio Qt add-in (download from [here](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/)): it will handle all the pre-processing steps required by some of Qt functionalities (C++ classes moc'ing, UI compilation...). It will also associate Qt files (.ui, .qrc, .ts) to respective editors.

Basically, you create a new Qt project, then create the .ui (you can use the one that comes with the template), create a class that inherits from the respective widget (`QWidget`, `QDialog`, `QMainWindow`) (again, there is one with the default project). From that class you setup the UI (you *link* the .ui and the C++ class, let's say), create slots and connect them with the UI elements, etc.

For a step-by-step tutorial please take a look at [the official manual](http://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/index.html), specially the [getting started](http://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-getting-started.html) section.